# Changing filename extensions and tracking changes

Tags: python, join, replace, split

I want to change filename extensions (in Python language) in a list of files from '.hpp' to '.h'. After I make these changes to only the files with that extension, I want to create a new list called newfilenames with the changes.

I have tried to create a program that works, but I can't quite seem to wrap my head around the problem. Here's my attempt at a solution so far.

```
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames
# using as many lines of code as your chosen method requires.

filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
filenames2 = ".".join(filenames)
filenames3 = filenames2.split(".")
filenames4 = list(enumerate(filenames3))
for index, item in filenames4:
    if index % 2 != 0 and item == "hpp":
        item = 'h'
```

Comment: `item = 'h'` doe not _modify_ the string which is assigned to `item`. It just assigns another string to variable `item`, without touching the previous one. In fact, there is no way to modify any string in Python, because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
changed_filenames = []

# loop over all the filenames
for filename in filenames:
    # does this file name end in .hpp ?
    if filename.endswith(".hpp"):
        # make a new filename, omitting the final two characters
        filename = filename[:-2]
    # append the filename to the new list
    changed_filenames.append(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Thank you so much! This makes perfect sense! You're right! I just needed to create an empty list and use .endswith() and .append()! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use build in method ‘replace’ inside a list comprehension...

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
new = [name.replace(".hpp",".h") for name in filenes]
print(new)
>>> ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]

renamed = []
newnames = []

for filename in filenames:
    if filename.split(".")[1] == 'hpp':
        renamed.append(filename)
        newnames.append(filename.split(".")[0]+".h")

print (renamed)
print (newnames)
```

Output:

```
['stdio.hpp', 'sample.hpp', 'math.hpp']
['stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'math.h']
```

Comment: Please, use two lines for `renamed = []; newnames = []` - that is just ugly ;)

Comment: Lol. I prefer oneliners in general for variable initialization but well if you wish I will make you pleased ;)

Answer (score 0):

here you go, this is an answer that uses regular expressions, hope this can help

```
import re

filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]


def fileTypeConversion(filelist, extension, replacement):
    stripedfilenames = []
    for file in filelist:
        if file.endswith(f'{extension}'):
            file = re.sub(f'\.{extension}$', replacement, file)

            stripedfilenames.append(file)
        else:
            stripedfilenames.append(file)

    return stripedfilenames


print(fileTypeConversion(filenames, '.hpp', '.h'))
```